# How to get average size of a directory with given skip step

Tags: python

I have a directory with lots of files, I want to check every nth or fixed amount of files for its size, then extrapolate it to the total file count in that directory.

I tried something, but my precision and syntax is bad. By no means I ask to fix my code, its just an example of what doesn't work and look well.

I'm on Python 2.7

```
def get_size2(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    filesCount = len(files)
    samples = 5.0
    step = math.ceil(filesCount / samples)
    files = files[0::step]
    reminderCount = filesCount - len(files)
    reminderStep = float(reminderCount / len(files)) + 1
    total_size = 0
    for f in files:
        fp = os.path.join(path, f)
        if not os.path.islink(fp):
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp) * reminderStep
    return int(total_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully understanding what you are trying to do given the code, but I think you want to gather an estimated directory size given the average found in a sub sample.

You can iterate though files given a certain increment size by passing a third parameter to a for loop:

```
for count in range(0, len(files), samples):
    print(f"On count: {count}")
```

Also, I'm a bit lost by the reminderCount and reminderStep variables.

Essentially you want to evaluate what the average size of file you view is (total size you have viewed, divided by the total number of files you have looked at) You can multiply the average file size by the number of files in the directory to extrapolate what an expected directory size would be given the sample. Turning the above logic into a function would simplify the problem to the following:

```
import os
import math

def get_size2(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    filesCount = len(files)
    samples = 1
    files_counted = 0
    total_size = 0
    for count in range(0, len(files), samples):
        files_counted += 1
        f = files[count]
        fp = os.path.join(path, f)
        if not os.path.islink(fp):
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return int(total_size / files_counted) * filesCount

def main():
    print(f'{get_size2("./test/path")}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This attempts to keep as many of the variables and as much as the structure as you posted, while adjusting the logic of the example. There are changes that I would recommend to the code such as passing the sample size as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You dont need to stick to my poor code, I just wanted to proof that I have tried and failed. I was looking for a solution with weighted average across samples, not a average of all samples * filesCount. This would improve precision.

Comment: What metric are you attempting to weight based on? Why would you weight one sample size differently from another?